# How to re-order my Pandas dataframe other than using the "columns.tolist()" method? I want a particular column to appear last always

Tags: python, pandas

my dataframe is like this:

```
In [57]: final_data
Out[57]: 
         monthyear       Date  Planned         CCM1         CCM2
0           Dec 15 2015-12-01      0.0     0.000000  2550.000000
1           Feb 16 2016-02-01      0.0     0.000000  4250.000000
2           Jan 16 2016-01-01      0.0  1540.000000  6800.000000
3           Nov 15 2015-11-01   3880.0   921.458157  1750.310038
4           Sep 15 2015-09-01   8000.0     0.000000  5191.197065
```

I need it to look like this below after re-ordering...

```
         monthyear       Date              CCM1         CCM2  Planned
0           Dec 15 2015-12-01          0.000000  2550.000000      0.0
1           Feb 16 2016-02-01          0.000000  4250.000000      0.0
2           Jan 16 2016-01-01       1540.000000  6800.000000      0.0
3           Nov 15 2015-11-01        921.458157  1750.310038   3880.0
4           Sep 15 2015-09-01          0.000000  5191.197065   8000.0
```

How can i do this, other than using "columns.tolist()" method?

Because my dataframe is dynamically generated... so except the columns like 'monthyear','Date' and 'Planned', every-other column name changes. I want the 'Planned' column to be always last. Please help..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only one column has been added, what is your reordering?

Comment: Ya sorry... That was by mistake... check now.. @Guillaume Thomas

Comment: My dataframe is dynamically generated.. so except the columns like 'monthyear','Date' and 'Planned', every-other column name changes. I want the 'Planned' column to be always last. Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a dumb way to solve my problem:

```
In [99]: final_data
Out[99]: 
Facility monthyear       Date  Planned         CCM1         CCM2
0           Dec 15 2015-12-01      0.0     0.000000  2550.000000
1           Feb 16 2016-02-01      0.0     0.000000  4250.000000
2           Jan 16 2016-01-01      0.0  1540.000000  6800.000000
3           Nov 15 2015-11-01   3880.0   921.458157  1750.310038
4           Sep 15 2015-09-01   8000.0     0.000000  5191.197065
```

convert column names to a list (column names are dynamic in my case excpet the column "Planned"):

```
In [100]: list=final_data.columns.tolist()

In [101]: list
Out[101]: ['monthyear', 'Date', 'Planned', u'CCM1', u'CCM2']

In [102]: list.remove('Planned')

In [103]: list.append('Planned')
```

Then:

```
In [104]: final_data[list]
Out[104]: 
Facility monthyear       Date         CCM1         CCM2  Planned
0           Dec 15 2015-12-01     0.000000  2550.000000      0.0
1           Feb 16 2016-02-01     0.000000  4250.000000      0.0
2           Jan 16 2016-01-01  1540.000000  6800.000000      0.0
3           Nov 15 2015-11-01   921.458157  1750.310038   3880.0
4           Sep 15 2015-09-01     0.000000  5191.197065   8000.0
```

Finally solved.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this:

```
       df
Out[17]: 
monthyear        Date  Planned         CCM1         CCM2
0    Dec 15  2015-12-01        0     0.000000  2550.000000
1    Feb 16  2016-02-01        0     0.000000  4250.000000
2    Jan 16  2016-01-01        0  1540.000000  6800.000000
3    Nov 15  2015-11-01     3880   921.458157  1750.310038
4    Sep 15  2015-09-01     8000     0.000000  5191.197065

In [18]: df=df[['monthyear','Date','CCM1','CCM2','Planned']]

In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
monthyear        Date         CCM1         CCM2  Planned
0    Dec 15  2015-12-01     0.000000  2550.000000        0
1    Feb 16  2016-02-01     0.000000  4250.000000        0
2    Jan 16  2016-01-01  1540.000000  6800.000000        0
3    Nov 15  2015-11-01   921.458157  1750.310038     3880
4    Sep 15  2015-09-01     0.000000  5191.197065     8000
```

or this:

```
df.reindex_axis(list(df.columns[:-3])+['CCM1','CCM2','Planned'],axis=1)
Out[13]: 
  monthyear        Date         CCM1         CCM2  Planned
0    Dec 15  2015-12-01     0.000000  2550.000000        0
1    Feb 16  2016-02-01     0.000000  4250.000000        0
2    Jan 16  2016-01-01  1540.000000  6800.000000        0
3    Nov 15  2015-11-01   921.458157  1750.310038     3880
4    Sep 15  2015-09-01     0.000000  5191.197065     8000
```

Comment: The problem is that my dataframe is dynamically generated.. so except the columns like 'monthyear','Date' and 'Planned', everyother column name changes. I want the 'Planned' column to be always last.